# Does jenkins provide a plugin to continue the job from where it failed previously

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I was trying to build an app using gradle tasks which is triggered using Jenkins. After running for few minutes the task gets failed for some reason. I fix the issue and re run the job and again. The job again reruns from first build step .

Was wondering if there is any plugin that could save the previous failed job state and rerun the job from there after the changes.

Like in maven we use -rf(resume from), So I was looking something like that.

The question is not specific to  gradle tasks. Lets say for example, if I have jenkins job with 10 build steps and it is failing at 8th build step, once I fix the build step, the next job execution should resume running from 8th build step. All these build steps are part of one job.

Note: For this case, I understand that I can run the build from command line on the build machine directly and once succeeded I can integrate with Jenkins. But in our case, we don't have direct login access to the  build machine .  So wondering for jenkins to do the magic

Could some one please help me with your answers please

Answer (score 1):

First thing you would have to do is, if you arent already, to start using Jenkins Pipeline stages. That would help define the stages in logical blocks of build scripts.
But to your point to resume from a certain stage, yes there is a `Checkpoint Plugin` which is pretty cool https://www.cloudbees.com/products/cloudbees-jenkins-platform/enterprise-edition/features/checkpoints-plugin

Unfortunately, the Cloudbees team has this available only in Enterprise Edition(paid) of Jenkins.
I talked to the core members on IRC if they plan to open-source this, and they are not ready for it :/

Comment: I already had this solution in my mind.But didn't go for it because implementing Jenkins pipeline stages is not the right choice to opt in the situation I'm . So was looking for a solution /idea that can help me . Anyways thanks very much !!

Comment: @manuendla hmm if you wana go a hacky way, you can still do it. Basically, have multiple build scripts in your job, each script sets a flag in the form of lets say a file. when that script is, started flag is set and its turned off when script ends.